# Swift Question about segue and view controller

Tags: swift, realm, segue, cell

I am new in Swift and I am in the middle of developing money management apps using realm. In short, I have a parentVC which show all account in parentVC, and rightBarButton which perform segue to AddAccVC, all things had sorted out and successfully.

However, if user wanted to edit the certain cellForRow at IndexPath, Should I create another VC as EditAccVC or to reuse the AddAccVC since edit and add is actually using the same fields and types of data.

If let say I choose to use back the AddAccVC for modification data. How do I execute it?

I am currently using rightBarButton to perform segue to AddAccVC in order to Add Account, if I was to use back the AddAccVC, I will need to perform segue from cellForRow to the same VC as selected Account and using the save Button to update changes. So If statement is required right? if yes, can guide me a through a sample so I can learn more in this execution?

Comment: you can use same VC for create and edit. maintain a flag for identify the status.

Comment: I agree with @DilanAnuruddha - the only reason to create a different view controller is if editing an existing account has different options than adding an account. I usually call my  viewControllers *AddEditAccountVC* to make it clear that it can both add, and edit the account.

Comment: Understood. I been trying to use the same VC and will implement the code accordingly to avoid too many confusing codes. However, my cell are sorted by realm.objects with keyPath : “date”. Which causing another problem in selected cell which showing different information when performed segue to addEditVC. Any easy setup to tackle this issue?

Comment: It's unclear with this *my cell are sorted by realm.objects* means. You should be following a MVC format and the cells display the corresponding data contained in the dataSource in the controller. If cell 2 is tapped, that would correspond to dataSource (assuming it's an array) element 2. If cell 5 is tapped, that corresponds to cell element 5 etc. (not taking sections/sub rows into account). Can you clarify?